# react native: what is the way to add frame around the picker to make it look nice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to add a frame around a picker ?
In my example I try to make a frame around the picker to make it look nice but I am not success and it is not clear to me why.
I'm running with Android and I can not see a frame around

```
import { Picker } from '@react-native-community/picker';


<Picker
          mode="dropdown"
          //pickerStyleType={}
          selectedValue={selectedValue}
          style={{
            color: 'black',
            placeholderTextColor: 'black',
            borderColor: 'black',
            borderWidth: 3,
            height: 50,
            width: 150,
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
          }}
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedValue(itemValue)}
        >
          <Picker.Item label="1" value="1" />
          <Picker.Item label="2" value="2" />
          <Picker.Item label="3" value="3" />
        </Picker>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your picker with a view like this

```js
<View style={ { borderWidth: 1 } }></View>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<View style={{borderWidth:1}}>
  <Picker
          mode="dropdown"
          selectedValue={selectedValue}
          style={{
            height: 50,
            width: 150,
          }}
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedValue(itemValue)}
        >
          <Picker.Item label="1" value="1" />
          <Picker.Item label="2" value="2" />
          <Picker.Item label="3" value="3" />
   </Picker>

<View/>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: You can wrap with the picker with a view so that styles of the border can apply to that view